# PowerShell: Appending Multiple Property Values to Array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append the $date variable which should contain the ticket creation date to an existing array that contains open tickets:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team2'
        TeamEmail = 'team2@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

$teamTickets = foreach($team in $teamConfig) {
  # Filter tickets based on team name
  $ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty TicketID
  $date = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty createdDate

    # Create an empty array
    $ticketIdArray = @()

    foreach ($id in $ticketIds) {
        $thisId = "
            <tr>
            <td>$($id)</td>
            <td>$($date)</td>
            </tr>
        "
        $ticketIdArray += $thisId
    }


  $team |Select TeamName,TeamEmail,@{Name='HTML';Expression={$ticketIdArray}}
}

$teamTickets.HTML
```

However this is the output I get (example):

```
<tr>
<td>INC0001</td>
<td>10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20</td>
</tr>
        

<tr>
<td>INC0002</td>
<td>10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20</td>
</tr>
        
<tr>
<td>INC0003</td>
<td>10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20 10/12/20</td>
</tr>
```

This is my desired output:

```
<tr>
<td>INC0001</td>
<td>10/12/20</td>
</tr>
        

<tr>
<td>INC0002</td>
<td>10/12/20</td>
</tr>
        
<tr>
<td>INC0003</td>
<td>10/12/20</td>
</tr>
```

It seems like for whatever reason the date is being appended based on the total number of teams.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Word of advice: separate _data modeling_ from _presentation_ - right now you're making choices about the final ouput format (HTML) in a context where you're really more interested in being able to meaningfully interrogate the data programatically

Comment: hey @KemalK.no luck either, I got the following error:
 Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method
     | is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@ScripterMike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14915444/scriptermike) and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026), using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection might get pretty expensive.
To avoid this, the correct *PowerShell* syntax is using the pipeline:

```
$ticketIdArray = foreach ($id in $ticketIds) {
     "
         <tr>
         <td>$($id.TicketID)</td>
         <td>$($id.createdDate)</td>
         </tr>
     "
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**i can not see the result can you try this**

```
$ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select TicketID,createdDate


# Create an empty array
$ticketIdArray = @()

foreach ($id in $ticketIds) {
    $thisId = "
        <tr>
        <td>$($id.TicketID)</td>
        <td>$($id.createdDate)</td>
        </tr>
    "
    $ticketIdArray += $thisId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kemal's solution may work, but I suggest that you use .NET `arraylists` instead of PS `arrays`.

PS `arrays` are of fixed size, which prevents their ironically native add/remove and related methods from working.

Meanwhile, .NET `arraylists` are not of fixed size, so those methods work. There is a performance benefit for `arraylist` manipulation if the arrays are big.

Instead of `$myArray = @()`, use `[collections.arraylist]$myArray = @()`.

Thereafter, you can simply execute `$myArray.Add($thisId), $myArray.Remove($thatId)`, etc.